# Convert table into json format

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am a new student of Postgres. I would like to convert a table into json format. Would someone please show me how to do it? Say, I have a table with 4 columns:

```
ticker   fin_item   year     amount
aapl     cash       fy2019   100
appl     cash       fy2020   150
apple    debt       fy2019   200
apple    debt       fy2020   250
```

I would like to insert these data into a new table, using the row fin_item as the new keys:

```sql
create table t_newtable(
    ticker varchar(10)
    cash jsonb
    debt jsonb
);
```

how can I convert this into this json format:

```
{"ticker":"aapl","cash":{"fy2019":100","fy2020":150"}
,{"ticker":"aapl","debt":{"fy2019":200","fy2020":250"}
```

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need an insert statement with conditionals along with `JSONB...OBJECT` type functions in order to insert JSONB values per each `ticker` and `fin_item` value group such as

```sql
INSERT INTO t_newtable
SELECT ticker,
       CASE WHEN fin_item = 'cash' THEN
            JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('ticker', ticker, fin_item,JSONB_OBJECT_AGG(year, amount)) 
        END,
       CASE WHEN fin_item = 'debt' THEN
            JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('ticker', ticker, fin_item,JSONB_OBJECT_AGG(year, amount)) 
        END
  FROM t
 GROUP BY ticker, fin_item
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=dd528a051aa2e9b72ca548c3ee5fa92d)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help!.

Comment: Is it possible for me to change query somehow so that they will insert into  t_newtable that  has only 2 columns ticker and fin_item. Under the ticker column, will have rows of 'apple', and under the fin_item will have rows of json objects : {"cash": {"fy2015": 100.0, "fy2016": 110.0, "fy2017": 120.0, "fy2018": 130.0, "fy2019": 140.0, "fy2020": 150.0}}
,{"debt": {"fy2015": 200.0, "fy2016": 210.0, "fy2017": 220.0, "fy2018": 230.0, "fy2019": 240.0, "fy2020": 250.0}}
,{"acc_rec": {"fy2015": 600.0, "fy2016": 610.0, "fy2017": 620.0, "fy2018": 630.0, "fy2019": 640.0, "fy2020": 650.0}}

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you so much again for your help, Mr. Ozhan! I use this query: INSERT INTO t_newtable
SELECT ticker,
        JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(item, JSONB_OBJECT_AGG(year, amount))
FROM t_items
GROUP BY t_items.ticker, t_items.item;

Comment: you're welcome @TimB , have a nice study.